# How do I add a template to a theme using a plugin?

Tags: plugins, templates

I need a page template to be used with my plugin. I don't need to replace a theme template such as single or archive.

Normally I'd use

```
/*
* Template Name: Blah Blah Blah
*/
```

to add a template to the page options, however, this isn't working in the plugin, as expected. I know how to add a template for a custom post type in a plugin. However, I need this to be an option the templates dropdown in the page options.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a fairly simple approach I was able to get working within a plugin. You'll want to reference  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_page_templates/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/ as you review the code below.

```
<?php
//Add our custom template to the admin's templates dropdown
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'pluginname_template_as_option', 10, 3 );
function pluginname_template_as_option( $page_templates, $theme, $post ){

    $page_templates['template-landing.php'] = 'Example Landing Page';

    return $page_templates;

}

//When our custom template has been chosen then display it for the page
add_filter( 'template_include', 'pluginname_load_template', 99 );
function pluginname_load_template( $template ) {

    global $post;
    $custom_template_slug   = 'template-landing.php';
    $page_template_slug     = get_page_template_slug( $post->ID );

    if( $page_template_slug == $custom_template_slug ){
        return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . $custom_template_slug;
    }

    return $template;

}
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot use $this as parameter`

Comment: Thanks for the note @Lee. As of PHP 7 you can no longer use `$this` as a parameter since it has a special use for object-oriented programming which you can read more about at http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php. I've updated `$this` to now be `$theme` since the theme object is what the parameter is referring to.

Comment: I found just removing `$this` also seems to work fine

Comment: I would recommend against removing `$this` since that will most likely generate a PHP notice, warning or error. The last parameter within `add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'pluginname_template_as_option', 10, 3 );` notes that three variables are being passed to the function. If you remove one then the code doesn't match up and your `$post` variable is actually now the `$this` variable which you probably don't want. I'd recommend digging into https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters to see a little more of how this works and why it's a better approach to change the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight forward way to this, as per my knowledge. I have tried to search as well, and did not find any better solution than the below one.

Below codes will provide you exactly what you are looking for:

```
class PageTemplater {

    /**
     * A Unique Identifier
     */
     protected $plugin_slug;

    /**
     * A reference to an instance of this class.
     */
    private static $instance;

    /**
     * The array of templates that this plugin tracks.
     */
    protected $templates;


    /**
     * Returns an instance of this class. 
     */
    public static function get_instance() {

            if( null == self::$instance ) {
                    self::$instance = new PageTemplater();
            } 

            return self::$instance;

    } 

    /**
     * Initializes the plugin by setting filters and administration functions.
     */
    private function __construct() {

            $this->templates = array();


            // Add a filter to the attributes metabox to inject template into the cache.
            add_filter(
                'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args',
                 array( $this, 'register_project_templates' ) 
            );


            // Add a filter to the save post to inject out template into the page cache
            add_filter(
                'wp_insert_post_data', 
                array( $this, 'register_project_templates' ) 
            );


            // Add a filter to the template include to determine if the page has our 
            // template assigned and return it's path
            add_filter(
                'template_include', 
                array( $this, 'view_project_template') 
            );


            // Add your templates to this array.
            $this->templates = array(
                    'goodtobebad-template.php'     => 'It\'s Good to Be Bad',
            );

    } 


    /**
     * Adds our template to the pages cache in order to trick WordPress
     * into thinking the template file exists where it doens't really exist.
     *
     */

    public function register_project_templates( $atts ) {

            // Create the key used for the themes cache
            $cache_key = 'page_templates-' . md5( get_theme_root() . '/' . get_stylesheet() );

            // Retrieve the cache list. 
            // If it doesn't exist, or it's empty prepare an array
            $templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates();
            if ( empty( $templates ) ) {
                    $templates = array();
            } 

            // New cache, therefore remove the old one
            wp_cache_delete( $cache_key , 'themes');

            // Now add our template to the list of templates by merging our templates
            // with the existing templates array from the cache.
            $templates = array_merge( $templates, $this->templates );

            // Add the modified cache to allow WordPress to pick it up for listing
            // available templates
            wp_cache_add( $cache_key, $templates, 'themes', 1800 );

            return $atts;

    } 

    /**
     * Checks if the template is assigned to the page
     */
    public function view_project_template( $template ) {

            global $post;

            if (!isset($this->templates[get_post_meta( 
                $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true 
            )] ) ) {

                    return $template;

            } 

            $file = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__). get_post_meta( 
                $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true 
            );

            // Just to be safe, we check if the file exist first
            if( file_exists( $file ) ) {
                    return $file;
            } 
            else { echo $file; }

            return $template;

    } 


}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'PageTemplater', 'get_instance' ) );
```

[Here is the full tutorial](http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-page-templates-plugin/) with details of what is happening and why.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `theme_page_templates` filter to inject your page template.

For example:

```
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'filter_inject_page_templates' );

filter_inject_page_templates( $templates ) {
    $path               = 'path/to/the/template/relative/to/the/theme/folder';
    $templates[ $path ] = 'Name of the template that displays in dropdown;
    return $templates;
}
```

You may have to play around with the  `$path` value to get it correct but that should work.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I note that you can't use "../" in the $path because WP applies a validate_file() to that path, and it will sens the '../" as a directory traversal, and will fail that attempt.  It's not clear if you can specify an absolute path as $path; the docs seem to indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer from jg314](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/253059/203510) works beautifully for pages. With a small adjustment it works for custom post types too. The key is to use the custom post type slug in the name of the first filter. So for a custom post type with slug `landing-page` it would be:

```php
add_filter( 'theme_landing-page_templates', 'pluginname_template_as_option', 10, 3 );
```

The rest is the same.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_post_type_templates/